# Unable to determine how to make Banno Auth work for me

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I need to understand how to make a Plugin in Banno for banks to access my user registration API. Banks can integrate this API into their website or APP portals to enroll their users into my website.

I had tried to create a plugin using Digital Garden examples provided but I am not able to understand how to feed input via this digital garden plugin.

My API isn't integrated with standard oAuth. Some banks want to integrate our API using Banno. Can anyone help me?

For example, my API "https://someURl.com/api/user_registration" require some input from credentials from BANK like bankUsername and password, followed by user information like their name, phone number, address, city, state, zip, etc.

How do I link this with Banno to create a plugin or service that a BANK can use via Banno oAuth Framework?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to know is that the Digital Toolkit *never* shares usernames and passwords with developers. Instead, we use OAuth and OpenID Connect as part of our [Authentication Framework](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/getting-started/).

After integrating with the Authentication Framework, you'll have access to authenticated information about the user via the [Identity Token](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/tokens/#identity-tokens) (an OpenID Connect concept).

The *claims* that can be provided in the Identity Token are described in [Authentication Framework - OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/openidconnectoauth/).